# Cannot connect to a function within an add_submenu_page() using OOP

Tags: wordpress, oop, plugins, submenu

This is my first transition to OOP in a WordPress plugin.

I am trying to create a submenu in Settings and the associated function to drive an admin screen.

The code below creates the menu item successfully but when I select the menu item, I receive the following error:

> call_user_func_array(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback, function "aa_admin_nsp_signoff_nav" not found or invalid function name.

Any insight to what I'm doing wrong is greatly appreciated!

```php
    class AaSignTheForm {
    
        public function __construct() {  
    
            add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'aa_nsp_signoff_submenu' ) );
        }
    
    
        public function aa_nsp_signoff_submenu() {
        
            add_submenu_page(
                'options-general.php',
                'Nominal Sale Price Signoff',
                'NSP Signoff',
                'administrator',
                'aa-signoff',
                'aa_admin_nsp_signoff_nav' );
        }
    
    }
    new AaSignTheForm();
```

Comment: In your call to add_submenu_page, you give 'aa_admin_nsp_signoff_nav', and the error says that function doesn't exist.  I don't see it in your question, so I would start by adding that function to your class.

Answer (score 0):

I just added `$this` in an array for the callable function:

```php
add_submenu_page(
    'options-general.php',
    'Nominal Sale Price Plugin Signoff',
    'NSP Signoff',
    'administrator',
    'aa-signoff',
    array( $this, 'aa_admin_nsp_signoff_nav' ));
}
```